Basic units conversion
I have an aluminum building material whose technical spec sheet says its density is 2.70 and density units are given as (kg/m3) × 103. I also know 1 kg of the material costs 3 USD. What would the cost per square meter ($/m2) be?
Steps:

2700 kg/m3 =>
1kg/0.00037 m3 =>
1kg/0.07181 m =>
1kg/0.00515 m2
3USD/1kg x 1kg/0.0052 m2 = 581.70 USD / m2

This number looks wrong based on context. I'm think there might be an error in step 3. Thanks,

per square meter will also need a thickness.

It depends on the sheet thickness.
For a thickness of say 1 mm, the cost will be:
$$Cost= \frac{2.7*1000*$3}{1000}=$8.1$$
So we multiply the sheet Thickness in mm by 8.1, say for a 5.5 mm thickness, the price is
$$Cost= 5.5*8.1=44.55$$
Of course, the manufacturer can set a different price.

In step 3, you simply took the cube root of 0.00037 m3.
All this tells you is that a 1 kg cube of the material will be 7.18 cm on a side.
In order to determine the cost per square meter, you'll need to know the thickness of the material when it is applied.
At this point, we know that it costs \$3.00 per .00037 m3, or \$8100 per m3.
If the application is, say 1 cm, then we can multiply the two together to get the cost per square meter:
$$\frac{\\\$8100}{\text{m}^3} × 0.01 \text{ m} = \frac{\\\$81}{\text{m}^2}$$

Thanks very much, very clear!
